# Declare not working in funtion using postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

This is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.func_leonard_test2(
    IN url text,
    OUT translation text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$BEGIN

DECLARE tempo text;

SELECT CONCAT(translate,'=true') INTO tempo FROM seo_content WHERE name=url;    

    CASE

        WHEN tempo = 'location_town' THEN

            SET translation = 'A';

        ELSE

            SET translation = 'B';   

    END CASE;

END;$BODY$
```

I'm having trouble declaring tempo.

This is the output:

> ERROR:  invalid type name "CONCAT(translate,'=true') INTO tempo FROM
>   seo_content WHERE name"

Even when I remove concat and I just keep translate, I get

> ERROR:  invalid type name "translate INTO tempo FROM seo_content WHERE
>   name"

Thanks

Comment: try declaring before begin.. is `translation` some column?.. you need return in function that returns not void

Comment: translate is a column and translation is the OUT var

Comment: ah,I C, and `SET translation = 'A';` what should do?..

Comment: it defines the output value, either A or B based on local variable tempo coming from the table.

Comment: `SET` sets configuration parameter, not a variable value - try my answer, maybe It does what you want?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.func_leonard_test2(
    IN url text,
    OUT translation text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$

DECLARE tempo text;
BEGIN

SELECT CONCAT(translate,'=true') INTO tempo FROM seo_content WHERE "name"=url;    

    CASE

        WHEN tempo = 'location_town' THEN

            translation := 'A';

        ELSE

            translation := 'B';   

    END CASE;

END;$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```